How do I interact with, search, and replace scene breaks in MS Word?
I've got a fairly straightforward issue, but none of the guides or documentation can lend me a helping hand. It feels weird, and I suspect I'm using some poor search terms.
In Word, there's a long line across the page that acts as a scene break, at least in novel writing. generally, tying three stars then an enter or space will 'autocorrect' to a scene break. Okay, cool.
Before mods get a little trigger happy: yes, Scene break, NOT line break, section break, or paragraph break.
I've got a document with a ton of existing scene breaks in it, and I'd like to do a bulk 'find and replace' on all of them. This is to turn the 'MS Word Scene Breaks' into three asteriks, so when I import the document to Atticus, the three asteriks turn into an 'Atticus Scene Break'.
Stupid to modify a scene break so another program can recognize it as a scene break and treat it properly, as opposed to the second program recognizing a scene break from the start? Yes.
Special characters probably needed, so a ^ search of some sort. Haven't been able to work out which letters, no matter how much I search, documentation I pull up, etc. Unless it's a unicode of some sort...?
No search I can come up with can find the scene breaks. Nothing I've tried on the keyboard will find it, and it's a 150k+ word document, with ~400 scene breaks in it. Manually 'just fixing it' would be a nightmare.
How do I search and replace scene breaks in Word? I'm very open to using VBA for this.


In Search/Replace, if you select a Scene Break, can you paste it into the Search box? 2. If you reveal all characters, search for * * * (https://jwmanus.wordpress.com/2015/09/18/ms-word-a-primer-for-indie-writers-part-ii-scene-breaks-page-breaks-and-sections/) 3. The extra height line of a Scene Break may be implemented in MS Word as a paragraph style, rather than as hidden characters. Search on that style (https://wordribbon.tips.net/T011741_Searching_for_Styles.html).


Thanks, I'll look into that!

For people like me, can you show us an image of those scene breaks? Are they lines you included yourself?

That is a paragraph border (bottom) inserted by AutoFormat as you type
The simplest method is to turn this into an actual paragraph style and apply that. Then search for that style.
Otherwise, you will need to duplicate the border in the advanced Find box. It is under borders and shading.
